# Disable the function of the lettrine command

Tags: lettrine

I would like to have two versions of my document. The differences depend on whether `kpfonts` is loaded or not. If it's not loaded I want to disable the`\lettrine` command and the arguments in the command should appear as normal text. Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{kpfonts}{%
%don't do anything in this MWE
}
{
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %just an example
%I also want to disable lettrine here
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Whatever}

\lettrine[findent=1pt, nindent=1pt]{N}{ow, let lipsum do the job:} \lipsum[1]

%Now, let lipsum do the job: \lipsum[1]. <<Achieve this with the above line

\end{document}
```

Is there a way of doing this so I wouldn't have to edit the actual text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `\renewcommand{\lettrine}[3][]{#2#3}` should do.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{kpfonts}
  {%
   %don't do anything in this MWE
  }
  {%
   \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}%just an example
   \renewcommand{\lettrine}[3][]{#2#3}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Whatever}

\lettrine[findent=1pt, nindent=1pt]{N}{ow, let lipsum do the job:} \lipsum[1]

Now, let lipsum do the job: \lipsum[1].

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked great, you forgot the `[]` in the code. `You can accept an answer in 9 minutes` :)

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi Sorry for the mistake. Fixed.